# How to compare values of two for loops and use if statement in django template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, for-loop, django-templates

This might be a confusing question.
I have three tables in sqllite: 1) Events 2) Delegates 3) EventDelegate
1st one stores all events, 2nd one stores all delegates, 3rd one contains the eventid and delegateid to show that the particular delegate is attending that particular event.
In my event details page i only want to show the delegates whose id are present in the event_delegate table along with that event id. Currently im using this code but not working

**views.py**

```
def event_det(request, eid):
    data = Event.objects.filter(id=eid) //SELECTING ONLY THE CLICKED EVENT
    data2 = Delegate.objects.all() // SELECTING ALL THE DELEGATES FROM DB
    data3 = EventDelegate.objects.filter(event_id=eid) //SELECTING RECORDS FROM EVENT_DELEGATE WHERE eventid is eid
    return render(request, 'event_details.html', {'event': data, 'delegates': data2, 'selectdelegates': data3})
```

**template**

```
<tbody>
   {% for del in delegates %}
   {% for sd in selectdelegates %}
   {% if del.id == sd.delegate_id %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{ del.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ del.first_name }} {{ del.last_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ del.email }}</td>
      <td>{{ del.phone }}</td>
      <td>{{ del.company }}</td>
      <td>{{ del.designation }}</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'delegate' dataset_id=del.dataset_id %}">View</a></td>
   </tr>
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I can share more details if required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relationship between event and event delegate like this:

```
class EventDelegate(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    delegate = models.ForignKey(Delegate, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Then you can try like this:

```
def event_det(request, eid):
    data = Event.objects.get(id=eid) //SELECTING ONLY THE CLICKED EVENT
    return render(request, 'event_details.html', {'event': data})

# template

{% for e in event.eventdelegate_set.all %}
     <tr>
      <td>{{ e.delegate.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ e.delegate.first_name }} {{ e.delegate.last_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ e.delegate.email }}</td>
      <td>{{ e.delegate.phone }}</td>
      <td>{{ e.delegate.company }}</td>
      <td>{{ e.delegate.designation }}</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'delegate' dataset_id=e.delegate.dataset_id %}">View</a></td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternative solution:

```
#view
def event_det(request, eid):
    data = EventDelegate.objects.filter(id=eid) //SELECTING ONLY THE CLICKED EVENT
    return render(request, 'event_details.html', {'event_delegates': data})

# template

{% for e in event_delegates %}
  // rest of the code as above example
```

More information can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/).

Comment: isnt this line should be like this 
```
data = EventDelegate.objects.get(event_id=eid) //SELECTING ONLY THE CLICKED EVENT
```

Comment: i think in ur answer views.py code is incomplete. please can you provide the full view function event_det()??? please

Comment: I think it can be done both ways, both by querying `Event` or `EventDelegate`? I am reverse querying from `Event` here. But you can use `EventDelegate` as well. See my updated answer:

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, EventDelegate models have ForeignKey to an Event and to a Delegate. So what you want is a queryset of EventDelegate objects that are linked to the event in question.

```
ed_qs = EventDelegate.objects.filter( event_id = event.id )
```

(maybe add `.order_by( "delegate__lastname")` for alpha ordering and `.select_related()`

pass this to your template, and

```
<tbody>
{% for ed in ed_qs %}

   <tr>
   {{ed.delegate.whatever}} ...
```

Alternatively you might use `.annotate` in the queryset to copy the desired fields of the linked delegate onto the returned objects. You'd then refer to the annotations, via your chosen annotation names such as  `{{ed.delegate_firstname}}`.My guess is that this would be maximally efficient, if that matters.